# Change values if some other observation is updated as well in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyr

I would appreciate some help in the following. Here is some toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                 V1 = c(5, 10, 5, 15, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0, 8, 1, 3))
```

The idea is to progressively split the data into groups `g`, assigning to a new column `y` the maximum value within a group in column `V2`, in each step of the progress using
less stringent criteria. In this case there are 2 steps.

The matching should continue until each group has 5 elements, or until all steps are made.
The first step is simple - rows with the same `id1` should belong to the same group:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  V1 = c(5, 10, 5, 15, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0, 8, 1, 3),
                    g = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  y = c(2, 2, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8))
```

For the second step, I want to pair together values that have `V1` within 5 units of each other OR were paired together in step 1.

```
df2 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                   V1 = c(5, 10, 5, 15, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                   V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0, 8, 1, 3),
                   g = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                   y = c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)).
```

Note that two things should happen:

1. Values with `id1 = 1` and `id2 = 2` are grouped together. This should happen because of the second and third rows: `|10 - 5| <= 5`. But even if this is not true for, say, rows 2 and 4, or 3 and 4, they should still be grouped together, because observations that were grouped in the first step should not be unmatched in the second.
2. The group with `id1 = 3` does not change, since it already had 5 components.

OBS: I don't care very much about the name `g` in each group, only about `y`.

How could I run a code that makes this happen for a larger dataset with more steps and more complicated
conditions within each step?

I know how to perform each classification independently, but don't know how to make the updating process work. I would give preference to answers using `tidyverse`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first part can be by using `dplyr` or `tidyverse`

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                 V1 = c(5, 10, 5, 15, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 V2 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 7, 4, 0, 8, 1, 3))

df1 <- df1 %>% group_by(id1) %>% mutate(g= id1, y= max(V2))
```

I could not really understand the second part.

Comment: I know the first step, the problem was actually the second. I've detailed it a bit more